# Heroku-Addon Provisioning - Auth0

Tags: heroku, auth0

I'm facing an issue while trying to add the auth0 addon to my Heroku app which I've created in Private Space.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUr8i.png)

Comment: I suggest you contact Heroku support. Private Spaces is a paid feature, so you should get plenty of attention.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be directed to Heroku support and [customer service-related questions are off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/354577)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.